# Flash Builder configuration to emulate Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

Has anyone successfully emulated the samsung galaxy S4 in their FLASH BUILDER? If yes, can you please let me know the config used? I am currently using the below config and it fails to replicate the S4;

[image]

Above config doesn't work good and when I try running the emulator with the above config it looks like a tablet.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question because the images and fonts in my application looked very tiny in a S4 device and I want to reproduce the issue in the emulator so that its easy to fix. But the issues were not getting reproduced with Flash Builder 4.6 + Flex SDK 4.6 combination. So I made the following changes;

1. Upgraded from Flash Builder 4.6 to 4.7
2. Upgraded from Flex SDK 4.6 to 4.10
3. Used the same protrait width (1080) and height(1920) mentioned in the image.

The emulator now replicates the issues which I see in the actual S4 device. But the screen size is huge as like a tablet.